# Angular 8 Lazy Loading and Routing not working correctly

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have the following simple application hierarchy at this time.

```
/home
/admin
/admin/customers
/admin/customers/:id
/admin/orders
/admin/orders/:Id
```

With Angular Routing, I am having trouble with my lazy loading modules, where the basic generated pages just do not load.  I have the simple generated components that have the  works! text.  This text however does not show up. I will use an AuthGuard in the future to protect access to Admin, but right now, I just want to see that I move through the application correctly.

The Adminstrator component is a simple link of buttons to move to `/admin/customers` and `/admin/orders`, which today are simple lists of some sample static data. These are simply displayed using a `*ngFor` statement.  Each component, when it was the home page, or if the selector is included in the HomeComponent.html does display correctly. My routing does not seem to work correctly.  I am trying to only load the Customer components in the customer module as this will then be self contained, similar with the orders, and then new features in the future.

app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'admin', loadChildren: () => import('./administration.module').then(m => m.AdministrationModule) },
    { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';

@NgModule({
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        HomeComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        AppRoutingModule
    ],
    providers: []
})
export class AppModule { }
```

admin-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AdministratorComponent } from '@admin/administrator/administrator.component';

const AdministratorRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: AdministratorComponent, /* canActivate: [AuthGuard], */ children: [
        { path: 'customers', loadChildren: () => import('./customers/customers.module').then(m => m.CustomerModule) },
        { path: 'orders', loadChildren: () => import('./orders/orders.module').then(m => m.OrderModule) },
    ]}
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(AdministratorRoutes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AdministrationRoutingModule { }
```

admin.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { AdministrationRoutingModule } from '@admin/administration-routing.module';

import { AdministratorComponent } from '@admin/administrator/administrator.component';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [AdministratorComponent],
    exports: [
    ],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        // Has to be last loaded module
        AdministrationRoutingModule,
    ]
})
export class AdministrationModule { }
```

customers-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { CustomerListComponent } from './customer-list/customer-list.component';
import { CustomerEditComponent } from './customer-edit/customer-edit.component';

const CustomerRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: CustomerListComponent,
        children: [
            { path: 'customers/:id', component: CustomerEditComponent }
        ]
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(CustomerRoutes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class CustomerRoutingModule { }
```

customers.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { CustomerRoutingModule } from './customer-routing.module';
import { CustomerListComponent } from './customer-list/customer-list.component';
import { CustomerEditComponent } from './customer-edit/customer-edit.component';


@NgModule({
    declarations: [CustomerListComponent, CustomerEditComponent],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        CustomerRoutingModule
    ]
})
export class CustomerModule { }
```

orders-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { OrderListComponent } from './order-list/order-list.component';
import { OrderEditComponent } from './order-edit/order-edit.component';

const OrderRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: OrderListComponent,
        children: [
            { path: 'orders/:id', component: OrderEditComponent }
        ]
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(OrderRoutes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class OrderRoutingModule { }
```

orders.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { OrderRoutingModule } from './order-routing.module';
import { OrderListComponent } from './order-list/order-list.component';
import { OrderEditComponent } from './order-edit/order-edit.component';


@NgModule({
    declarations: [OrderListComponent, OrderEditComponent],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        OrderRoutingModule
    ]
})
export class OrderModule { }
```

Comment: do you already have your component with the router-outlet?

Comment: The main page is the only <router-outlet> is in the app-component.html.

Comment: you still need another router outlet to navigate within your child routes

Comment: @jalex19 So the only way to get the update, is to have a subpage with a new <router-outlet> display the information?  So children are not shown on the main single page, following the tree routing, but as actual children of a parent page.  If you have menus that have deep tree style routes (/admin, /admin/setup, /admin/setup/users, /admin/setup/users/:id) then these have to show as a child of Admin, then Setup has a <router-outlet> for the users, with the users then having a <router-outlet> for the main list, and then an add/edit page for users as well?

Comment: So I guess to get what I want, my routes all have to be in the main route module, and not child routes.  I did not want to have a new part of a page for each module that was getting routed to.  I wanted the links to work on the main page, but be added as I expand the application and add additional modules for new functionality.

Comment: Yes, I think you need the child router outlet to map the child routes and pull them into creen, otherwise you will always see the component for your main child route